# for-each vs for vs while

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I wonder what is the best way to implement a "for-each" loop over an ArrayList or every kind of List.

Which of the followings implementations is the best and why? Or is there a best way?

Thank you for your help.

```
List values = new ArrayList();
```

values.add("one");
values.add("two");
values.add("three");
...

//#0
for(String value : values) {
    ...
}

//#1
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    String value = values.get(i);
    ...
}

//#2
for(Iterator it = values.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String value = it.next();
    ...
}

//#3
Iterator it = values.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String value = (String) it.next();
    ...
}

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99164/iterate-with-for-loop-or-while-loop

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#3 has a disadvantage because the scope of the iterator `it` extends beyond the end of the loop. The other solutions don't have this problem.

#2 is exactly the same as #0, except #0 is more readable and less prone to error.

#1 is (probably) less efficient because it calls `.size()` every time through the loop.

#0 is usually best because:

- it is the shortest
- it is least prone to error
- it is idiomatic and easy for other people to read at a glance
- it is efficiently implemented by the compiler
- it does not pollute your method scope (outside the loop) with unnecessary names

Comment: Nice answer. However, #1 is required when updating (if not just mutating the current item or building the results as a new list) and comes with the index. Since the `List<>` is an `ArrayList<>` in this case, the `get()` (and `size()`) is `O(1)`, but that isn't the same for all List-contract types.

Comment: #2 is the solution to use when you need to remove things during the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to use version 0. Take a peek at the section title *Use Enhanced For Loop Syntax* at [Android's documentation for Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html). That page has a bunch of goodies and is very clear and concise.

Comment: That is for android but in this question there is no Android TAG, and also it depends in what you need at the end.

Answer (score 1):

#0 is the easiest to read, in my opinion, but #2 and #3 will work just as well. There should be no performance difference between those three.

In almost no circumstances should you use #1. You state in your question that you might want to iterate over "every kind of List". If you happen to be iterating over a `LinkedList` then #1 will be n^2 complexity: not good. Even if you are absolutely sure that you are using a list that supports efficient random access (e.g. `ArrayList`) there's usually no reason to use #1 over any of the others.

Comment: It's not true that #1 should *never* be used. It is the only way to *change the cell* of a List that pass, although the time complexity (which is not implied with List) must be considered.

Comment: Change the cell? What do you mean?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) { x.set(i, i * 2); }` Granted that's a silly example and in many cases just creating a new List is better. Also, it might be more appropriate to restrict to ArrayList in such cases. But it *is* a counter to *never*.

Comment: Right. Fair enough. Although I'd still suggest using a `ListIterator` and it's `set` method in preference. Then it will still efficiently work with non-random-access lists.

Comment: I've softened the "never" a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

In response to this comment from the OP.

> However, #1 is required when updating (if not just mutating the current item or building the results as a new list) and comes with the index. Since the List<> is an ArrayList<> in this case, the get() (and size()) is O(1), but that isn't the same for all List-contract types.

Lets look at these issues:

It is certainly true that `get(int)` is not `O(1)` for all implementations of the `List` contract.  However, AFAIK, `size()` is `O(1)` for all `List` implementations in `java.util`.  But you are correct that #1 is suboptimal for many `List` implementations.  Indeed, for lists like `LinkedList` where `get(int)` is `O(N)`, the #1 approach results in a `O(N^2)` list iteration.

In the `ArrayList` case, it is a simple matter to manually *hoist* the call to `size()`, assigning it to a (final) local variable.  With this optimization, the #1 code is significantly faster than the other cases ... for `ArrayList`s.

Your point about changing the list while iterating the elements raises a number of issues:

- If you do this with a solution that explicitly or implicitly uses iterators, then depending on the list class you may get `ConcurrentModificationException`s.  If you use one of the concurrent collection classes, you won't get the exception, but the javadocs state that the iterator won't necessarily return all of the list elements.
- If you do this using the #1 code (as is) then, you have a problem.  If the modification is performed by the same thread, you need to adjust the index variable to avoid missing entries, or returning them twice.  Even if you get everything right, a list entry concurrently inserted before the current position won't show up.
- If the modification in the #1 case is performed by a different thread, it hard to synchronize properly.  The core problem is that `get(int)` and `size()` are separate operations.  Even if they are individually synchronized, there is nothing to stop the other thread from modifying the list between a `size` and `get` call.

In short, iterating a list that is being concurrently modified is tricky, and should be avoided ... *unless you really know what you are doing*.